# React-Native Firebase auth error message get stuck till second try

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I try to make a signUp method, but I have some issues with error handling. If I write a bad email, then a good it will create but the errorMessage is still in the previous state, but the user creating is run.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.pwd)
.then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Loading', this.setState({errorMessage: ''})))
.catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message, alert(this.state.errorMessage)}));
```

Eg.:

```
Write: asd@gmail ->
Click button: alert nothing ->
Write: asd@gmail.com ->
Click button: alert bad email but navigate to Loading Screen (successful account creating)
```

Any tips? :/ 
Thanks!

Comment: it work well if i just write errorMessage with simple text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setState syntax is not correct, you need to add a callback and alert function should be in a callback of setState. It should be as follows:

```
this.setState({
   errorMessage: error.message
},() => {
   alert(this.state.errorMessage);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong with `setState`, it should be
`this.setState({ params }, this.doSomething)`

`this.setState({ 
  errorMessage: error.message,
}, alert(this.state.errorMessage))`